# how do i create a variable from the output of another in bash

Tags: bash, variables, dynamic, eval

Here's an example script that doesn't work the way I expect:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dynamic in a b c; do
  myvar=$dynamic

  export $myvar="hi"

  echo $(eval "$myvar")
  echo $dynamic
done
```

I want the output would be:

```
hi

a

hi

b

hi

c
```

Any ideas?  I'm willing to stray away from this method, but I definitely want to be able to create a variable named from the output of an algorithm.  In this case it's just a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear that this is what you're looking for, but I think you want something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=A
b=B
c=C
for i in a b c; do
        eval $i=value_$i
        eval echo \$$i
done
echo $a  # Prints "value_a"
```

Comment: Yes sir.  You nailed it.  Although I don't need any of the above declarations, a=A, etc...  But that's essentially what I wanted.  Interpreting the $ literally, then evaluting the echo of that plus the $i.  Very clever.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`eval` has a tendency to cause bugs, so avoid it whenever possible; in this case it's much cleaner to use indirect expansion with `${!metavariable}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dynamic in a b c; do
  myvar=$dynamic

  export $myvar="hi"

  echo ${!myvar}
  echo $dynamic
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is the fix for your program. There are two things you got wrong:
The first is you don't need '$' when declaring variables.
The second is that calling eval will treat the content of myvar as a shell script. However you don't have "hi" defined anywhere as a command.

```
 for dynamic in a b c; do
     myvar=$dynamic

-    export $myvar="hi"
+    export myvar="hi"

-    echo $(eval "$myvar")
+    echo "$myvar"
     echo $dynamic
 done
```

Comment: I think you're missing the purpose of the question. I think the OP wants something similar to PHP's variable variables.